# Is there a way to programmatically determine the proper sizes for Apple's built-in controls?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, constants

When writing Cocoa apps, I do the majority of the user interface layout programmatically. For example:

```
NSRect popUpFrame = NSMakeRect(10, 10, 100, kDefaultPopUpButtonHeight);
NSPopUpButton * popUp = [[NSPopUpButton alloc] initWithFrame:popUpFrame];
//...
```

My question is about that `kDefaultPopUpButtonHeight` constant. I currently maintain a source file full of such constants, and I fill in the proper sizes manually. I am able to determine the correct sizes by dropping a new control into a blank view in Interface Builder and then checking its properties to see what size IB gives it.

There must be a better way. Is it possible to access these values at runtime? Ideally, I would expect every `NSControl` to have a class method something like: `+(NSSize)defaultSize`, or, for controls like `NSButton` that have different default sizes depending on the particular button style used, something like `+(NSSize)defaultSizeForButtonStyle:(NSButtonStyle)buttonStyle`.

[Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIntro/XHIGIntro.html) has information about control layout and the spacing *between* controls, but it doesn't say anything about the proper sizes for individual controls.

Comment: “When writing Cocoa apps, I do the majority of the user interface layout programmatically.” Why? Nibs are so much easier, and don't require maintaining a header full of recorded implementation details.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: Personal preference, based on my own experiences. I started out using IB for everything, then migrated to uisng it only for layout. After I worked on an application in which we wrote a complete user interface from scratch (no Apple controls at all), I found that I was more comfortable (and more effective) with interface layout when I did everything in software.

Comment: IB is a great tool and it should be used when possible but it will never be able to compare to the ability to control the entire interface programatically. In the end we are developers and the tools are only effective if they save you time and frustration.  There are often times when IB gets in the way of what you need to accomplish, and for those times you need to program yourself.

Comment: I imagine that once developers who are gung-ho on hand coding interfaces ship a localized (international) app they'll learn to appreciate IB. GUIs by hand is fine if that's your thing, but it's not "the way", so to speak. Donald Knuth says "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." I always recommend using IB unless there is a very specific thing that cannot be accomplished while using it, then do only that one thing programatically. Default sizing of controls is one of those things that would take care of itself under IB.

Comment: I do not hand-code the UI for any kind of code optimization. Default control sizing is a small hiccup (and hence this question), but I still write hand-coded interfaces more effectively than I am able to with IB, and I find them far easier to maintain. One example is bindings: I set up all of the bindings for a particular portion of the interface in one method. I can arrange them logically, and I can add comments to them. With IB, individual bindings can be hard to find, and they are often distributed around multiple objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Peter, and would recomend that you use Interface Builder. But if that isn't appropriate in your situation, here's one way to find the best size for most controls:

```
NSSize idealSize = [[control cell] cellSize];
```

If you need more control over the sizing, you can use the -[NSCell cellSizeForBounds:] method.

Also, cellSize really gives you the minimum size for a control, not necessarily the best size. For example, for a Cocoa aqua style push button with the text "OK", it would return a width that more narrow than the HIG would recommend. For your purposes, it sounds like you're only interested in the fixed hight portion of the size. -[NSCell cellSize] should work great.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark this as accepted. I haven't had a chance to test it out until now, but cellSize is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!